# What can go up a chimney down, but not down a chimney up?

Tags: riddle

Here's one I know from childhood. I didn't see it on here, so I thought I would add it.

> What can go up a chimney down,  but not down a chimney up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> An umbrella. If "up" (open), you cannot pull it down a chimney (it's too wide); if it's "down" (closed), it will easily fit through.

Answer (score 6):

> Down

It goes up a chimney down, and in the unlikely case that it isn't burnt up and comes back down the chimney it would come down down.

Comment: I like this answer. Very unexpected. The only difference is you have "down down" as opposed to "down... up". I suppose this could be a second riddle when the after the first is guessed in social situations. "What goes up a chimney down, and goes down a chimney down." After the first answer is guessed, this one would throw them off. =)

Comment: It's funny, I came back to this realizing now I misunderstood your answer. You said "it would come down down" meaning "NOT come down up". I must have been tired when I replied. I like your answer even more now. Lol. I'm half tempted to change the correct answer. But as it stands, my including this riddle here is proved controversial in that every up-vote I get on this post is immediately down voted.

Answer (score 2):

Well, perhaps a possible answer is

> Smoke!

Comment: How can smoke be down and up, for going "up" a chimney down and "down" a chimney up?